# Unable to retrieve session state when navigating from login to homepage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, supabase

I'm following a [course on undemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/reactjs-with-supabase) and have hit a wall. I have been able to implement a login page and authentication. However once I navigate away from the login page, I see that session data is not kept. I can certainly do a `console.log(data)` after the line `const {data, error} = await signIn({email, password})` which returns me with all the session data.

However if I attempt to do the same on Nav.js with `console.log(user)` the value comes back as null. Is the value being nulled at some point?

I have also attempted running authprovider as an async function. However then I end up with the Nav only updating when I switch to another tab and come back.

### AuthContext.js async

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../supabaseClient";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const [sessionData, setSessionData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    //const session = supabase.auth.getSession();
    //const user = supabase.auth.getUser();

    //setUser(user);
    //console.log(user)

    const fetchData = async () => {
      await supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
        var access_token = session.access_token;
        setSessionData(session);
        setUserData(session.user)

      })
    }  
    fetchData();

  }, []);


  const value = {
    signUp: (data) => supabase.auth.signUp(data),
    signIn: (data) => supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(data),
    signOut: () => supabase.auth.signOut(),
    userData,
  };
  console.log(sessionData)
  console.log(userData)

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

### AuthContext.js original

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../supabaseClient";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const session = supabase.auth.getSession();

    setUser(session?.user ?? null);

    setLoading(false);

    const { data: {subscription} } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
      async (session) => {

        setUser(session?.user ?? null);
        setLoading(false);
        
      }
      
    );

    return () => {
        subscription?.unsubscribe();
      
  
    };
  }, []);

  const value = {
    signUp: (data) => supabase.auth.signUp(data),
    signIn: (data) => supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(data),
    signOut: () => supabase.auth.signOut(),
    user,
  };
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
  
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

### Login.js

```
import "./Auth.css";
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {useAuth} from '../../../contexts/AuthContext';

function Login() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();

  const [error,setError] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const {signIn } = useAuth();
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const email = emailRef.current.value;
    const password = passwordRef.current.value;

    const {data, error} = await signIn({email, password})

    if (error) {
      setError(error);
      setMessage("Error: " + error.message)
      return
    }
    navigate("/")
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <div className="text-center div">
      <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label htmlFor="inputEmail" className="sr-only">
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          ref={emailRef}
          type="email"
          id="inputEmail"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Email address"
          required
        />
        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="sr-only">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          ref={passwordRef}
          type="password"
          id="inputPassword"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Password"
          required
        />
        <div className="checkbox mb-3">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" defaultValue="remember-me" /> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
          Sign in
        </button>
        <Link to="/signup"><a>Sign Up</a></Link>
      </form>
      {message? <p>{message}</p> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

### Nav.js

```
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext"
import { useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const Nav = () => {

    const {user, signOut} = useAuth();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    console.log(user)
    async function handleSignOut() {
        await signOut()
        navigate("/")
    }
    
    return(
        <>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
        <div className="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                Menu
                <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                    <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="post.html">Sample Post</a></li>
                    <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    {user ? 
                    <li className="nav-item"><a onClick={handleSignOut} className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/">Sign Out</a></li>
                    :
                    <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/login" className="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4">Login</Link></li>}

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: Can you try updating your supabase-js and gotrue-js dependencies? Might be related to [this](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/pull/623).